# How to rotate an array of canvas rectangles

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas

I'm creating a [Pentomino](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentomino) puzzle game for a final project in a class I'm taking.  I've created all dozen of the required puzzle pieces and can drag those around [here](http://jsfiddle.net/delliottg/9shssnc9/).  And I've tried this code to rotate the array (without using `canvas.rotate()` & located at the very bottom of the fiddle), it basically swaps the X & Y coordinates when drawing the new piece:

```
var newPiece = targetPiece;
pieces.splice(pieces.indexOf(targetPiece), 1);
targetPiece = null;
console.log(newPiece);
var geometry = [];
for (var i = 0; i < newPiece.geometry.length; i++) {
    geometry.push([newPiece.geometry[i][3], newPiece.geometry[i][0]]);
}
var offset = [newPiece.offset[1], newPiece.offset[0]];
console.log(geometry);
console.log(offset);
newPiece.geometry = geometry;
newPiece.position = geometry;
newPiece.offset = offset;
pieces.push(newPiece);
console.log(pieces);
for (var j = 0; j < pieces.length; j++) {
    draw(pieces[j]);
}
```

This doesn't work properly, but has promise.

In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/delliottg/q85bx5bm/), I've isolated the problem down to a single piece and tried to use canvas.rotate() to rotate the array by double clicking, but what's actually happening is it's rotating each piece of the array (I think), which results in nothing happening because each block of the array is just a 50x50 rectangle and when you rotate a square, it still looks just like a square.

```
function doubleClickListener(e) {
var br = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
mouse_x = (e.clientX - br.left) * (canvas.width / br.width);
mouse_y = (e.clientY - br.top) * (canvas.height / br.height);
var pieceToggle = false;
for (var i = 0; i < pieces.length; i++) {
    if (onTarget(pieces[i], mouse_x, mouse_y)) {
        targetPiece = pieces[i];
        rotate(targetPiece);
    }
}
}

function rotate() {
targetPiece.rotationIndex = targetPiece.rotationIndex === 0 ?
1 : targetPiece.rotationIndex === 1 ?
2 : targetPiece.rotationIndex === 2 ?
3 : 0;
for (var j = 0; j < pieces.length; j++) {
    draw(pieces[j]);
}
}
```

Just FYI, I've tried creating the puzzle pieces as individual polygons, but could not figure out how to capture it with a mousedown event and move it with mousemove, so I abandoned it for the canvas rectangle arrays which were relatively simple to grab & move.

There's a brute force solution to this, and a total rewrite solution, both of which I'd rather avoid (I'm up against a deadline-ish).  The brute force solution is to create geometry for all possible pieces (rotations & mirroring), which requires 63 separate geometry variants for the 12 pieces and management of those states.  The rewrite would be to use [fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/) (which I'll probably do after class is over because I want to have a fully functional puzzle).

What I'd like to be able to do is rotate the array of five blocks with a double click (don't care which way it goes as long as it's sequential 90° rotations).

---

### Approaching a usable puzzle:

With lots of help from **@absolom**, here's what I have, you can drag with a mouse click & drag, rotate a piece by double clicking it, and mirror a piece by right clicking it (well, mostly, it won't actually rotate until you next move the piece, I'm working on that).  The Z-order of the pieces are manipulated so that the piece you're working with is always on top (it has to be the last one in the array to appear on top of all the other pieces):

[**Pentominoes II**](https://jsfiddle.net/delliottg/b4jm9s5c/)

---

### The final solution

I've just handed the game in for grading, thanks for all the help!  There was a lot more tweaking to be done, and there are still some things I'd change if I rewrite it, but I'm pretty happy with the result.

[**Pentominoes Final**](http://jsfiddle.net/delliottg/n02avkLm/)

Comment: Why do you use a Geometry array and a Position array which are initialized with the same values in each of your piece? If you swap the X and the Y of each of your entry in these arrays, the pieces are turned 90 degrees. Isn't it what you need? You are saying in your post that this doesn't work properly. Could you please explain your result?

Comment: The geometry array is the initial state of the piece.  Each piece needs a place for the mouse pointer to anchor, which I set at 0,0.  Otherwise if you do the original geometry where it's final position is, the mouse pointer is offset by deltas in XY.  I couldn't figure out a good way to fix that, so I use the position array to keep track of the actual position of the piece.  If you try to rotate it using the code I listed, it rotates up into the upper left of the canvas, and then skitters away to the bottom right when you try to subsequently move it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this [code](https://jsfiddle.net/nu2g4w55/) do what you need? The rotate method looks like this now:

```
   function rotate(piece) {
       for (i = 0; i < piece.geometry.length; i++) {
           var x = piece.geometry[i][0];
           var y = piece.geometry[i][2];
           piece.geometry[i][0] = -y;
           piece.geometry[i][3] = x;
       }
       drawAll();
   }
```

I simplified how your geometry and positioning was handled too. It's not perfect, but it can gives you some hints on how to handle your issues.

Please note that this solution works because each piece is composed of blocks with the same color and your rotations are 90 degrees. I only move the blocks around to simulate the rotation but nothing is rotated per-se. If you build your pieces differently or if you need to rotate at different angles, then you would need to go with another approach like transformation matrices.

**UPDATE**

Here is a better solution: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4g47mph9/1/)

Comment: Thanks!  I've adapted your code to my original code and mostly have it working (you have to move the piece before it rotates, but I'll figure that out).  I'm also going to study what you did in your fiddle (please don't delete it for a while, I'll fork it tomorrow so I can examine your methods).  I like the simpler piece management, but I couldn't immediately figure out how to properly add a new piece (it's been a very long day & ready for bed).  Thanks again!

Comment: I created another [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4g47mph9/1/) that seems  better. The geometry definition is separated from the piece so that you can share the same geometry definition with different pieces. The  Orientation is now in the Pentomino class with the Position. When you draw your piece, you then only have to  extract the geometry, rotate it, translate its position and then draw it with the desired size. __Please note that I forgot a couple 'var' in some for loops in my previous fiddle.__

Comment: Thanks again for the help, it's been incredibly valuable and I appreciate it.  Please see the OP for an update (at the bottom), that incorporates a lot of your code & suggestions

Comment: Happy to help. Good luck with your project.

Comment: Do you have an idea why the mirroring doesn't happen automatically like the rotation does?  I wonder if I need to somehow refresh the piece after a mirroring takes place?

Comment: Never mind, figured it out!  Forgot to tell it to redraw the pieces.

Answer (score 2):

**Quick & Dirty:**

The quick & dirty solution is when 2+ pieces are assembled you create a single image of them (using an in-memory canvas). That way you can move / rotate the 2-piece-as-1-image as a single entity.

**More Proper:**

If the 2+ piece assembly must later be disassembled, then you will need the more proper way of maintaining transformation state per piece. That more proper way is to assign a transformation matrix to each piece.

Stackoverflow contributor Ken Fyrstenberg (K3N) has coded a nice script which allows you to track individual polygons (eg your rects) using transformation matrices: https://github.com/epistemex/transformation-matrix-js

Comment: For your Q&D solution, do you mean using context.drawImage() with the array?  I don't ever have to disassemble the arrays once complete, just rotate and mirror them.

Comment: You can create an in-memory canvas and drawImage all the required the pieces to that canvas. Then use that in-memory canvas as an image source for the on-screen canvas. So: `onscreenContext.drawImage(offscreenCanvas,...` (and yes...an in-memory canvas can be used as an image source for `drawIamge`  -- nice, yes?

Comment: Thanks for your assistance in this, in the interest of time (deadline looming), I'm going to use @absolom's solution, but I want to study your suggestions as well, as I have other canvas projects I'd like to do.